# AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest returns content of PHP file instead of executing it

Tags: php, ajax, node.js

I want to execute a PHP script on a Linux server running node.js by using a call to XMLHttpRequest on the client.  Instead of executing the PHP script on the server, the script contents are returned.  Is there a node.js configuration change required for the PHP script to be executed on the server?  Also, since node.js is used for server side javascript, can I execute a javascript file, instead of a PHP file using XMLHttpRequest?

The goal is just to execute the script on the server just to do a simple task.  At this time, I don't need anything returned to the client.

Client Side:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("mailDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","phpfile.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Server side - PHP script phpfile.php

```
<?php
$to = "first.last@company.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: How are you trying to run the php file?  Is it saved as a `.php` file?  Is PHP installed correctly?

Comment: Please. I Beg. Paste Your Code.

Comment: The php file is a normal php file ending in .php,.  It works fine when XMLHttpRequest is called from the client, when the server is running Apache, but not when the server is running node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js and PHP are entirely different beasts. By default, node cannot execute PHP and will simply send the contents of the file to the client.

You can try something like [node-php-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php-server) to execute PHP within node, but I think that your best bet is to just install Apache or nginx and use it to execute PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess I'm confused on why it is possible to execute PHP, or ASP files within Apache, but not within node.  Is there some configuration change, or "hook" that can be used in node to execute these files, instead of sending the contents back to the client?

Comment: PHP runs as a plugin for Apache and nginx , but there is no similar thing for node. As I said in my answer, you could check out node-php-server, but I think it just runs php on the CLI for files it processes.